# purpose of using pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers, permutation

I'm having trouble understanding the purpose of using pointers. The code below is to print all permutations of a given string using pointers.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void swap(char *p1, char *p2) {
char pmt;
pmt = *p1;
*p1 = *p2;
*p2 = pmt;
}
void permutation(char *str, int index,int n ) {
int i; 
if (index == n) {
printf("%s ", str);
}
else {
for (i = index; i<=n; i++) {
swap((str+index), (str+i));
permutation(str, index+1, n);
swap((str+index), (str+i));
    }
  }
}

int main() {
char s[] = "ABCD";
int n = strlen(s);
permutation(s, 0, n-1);
printf("\n\n");
return 0;
}
```

If I were to remove the pointers, my swap function will now become

```
void swap(char p1, char p2) {
char pmt;
pmt = p1;
p1 = p2;
p2 = pmt;
}
```

I will still get back the same output as the output with pointers. However, the caveat is that my output will produce some warnings

```
grok1.c:23:6: warning: incompatible pointer to integer conversion passing 'char *' to parameter of type 'char'; dereference with * [-Wint-conversion]
swap((str+index), (str+i));
     ^~~~~~~~~~~
     *
grok1.c:10:16: note: passing argument to parameter 'p1' here
void swap(char p1, char p2) {
               ^
grok1.c:23:19: warning: incompatible pointer to integer conversion passing 'char *' to parameter of type 'char'; dereference with * [-Wint-conversion]
swap((str+index), (str+i));
                  ^~~~~~~
                  *
grok1.c:10:25: note: passing argument to parameter 'p2' here
void swap(char p1, char p2) {
                        ^
grok1.c:25:6: warning: incompatible pointer to integer conversion passing 'char *' to parameter of type 'char'; dereference with * [-Wint-conversion]
swap((str+index), (str+i));
     ^~~~~~~~~~~
     *
grok1.c:10:16: note: passing argument to parameter 'p1' here
void swap(char p1, char p2) {
               ^
grok1.c:25:19: warning: incompatible pointer to integer conversion passing 'char *' to parameter of type 'char'; dereference with * [-Wint-conversion]
swap((str+index), (str+i));
                  ^~~~~~~
                  *
grok1.c:10:25: note: passing argument to parameter 'p2' here
void swap(char p1, char p2) {

4 warnings generated.
ABCD ABCD ABCD ABCD ABCD ABCD ABCD ABCD ABCD ABCD ABCD ABCD ABCD ABCD ABCD ABCD ABCD ABCD ABCD ABCD ABCD ABCD ABCD ABCD
```

Appreciate it if someone could help to explain the warnings as I'm kind of struggling here. thanks!

Comment: Your version of swap will have no effect. You could actually test it to disprove your assumption.

Comment: If you change the signature of your function (the number and types of your arguments and the return type), you must also change how you call it: `swap(str[i], str[j])`. But as already said, that function swaps two local variables and won't have any effect on your sorting.

Comment: Despite what you say, your output is not the same with the non-pointer code. It's ABCD repeated 24 times whereas before it was all permutations.

Answer (score 1):

Before answer this question, you need to know two things first:
First, when you pass a string to a function, you actually pass the address to the first element in the array to it.
Second, there are two ways of passing those addressed to functions; either by value or by reference !
Now your permutation function accept an address as the first argument which is your string "ABCD"; now the problem is when you pass the string to swap function you don't give it two addresses of the strings you want to swap so swap function will create two copies of the strings and swap them internally and then delete the copies when the function terminate.
What you need to do is to pass the str by reference to change the original value

Answer (score 1):

Pointers are a fundamental aspect of C programming.  We *have* to use pointers in two cases:

- when we want a function to modify a parameter;
- when we want to track dynamically allocated memory;

Pointers are also useful in building dynamic data structures such as lists, trees, queues, etc.  We can use pointers to iterate over arrays or other sequences.  We can use pointers to hide or isolate implementation details (the `FILE` type is a good example of this). We can also use pointers to functions to implement callbacks or polymorphism, but I’ll be sticking to object pointers in this answer.

Object pointer values are obtained in one of three ways:

- using the unary `&` operator on a variable<sup>1</sup>;
- calling a library function that returns a pointer value, such as `malloc`, `calloc`, or `realloc` for allocating dynamic memory, but also things like `fopen`, `strchr`, `strtok`, etc.;
- using an array expression;

An object pointer value is *valid* if it points to an object during that object’s lifetime.  Attempting to read or write through an invalid pointer results in undefined behavior.

When you pass the array expression `s` to permutations, what you are actually passing is the address of the first element of the array.  Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&`, or is a string literal used to initialize a character array in a declaration, an expression of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted, or "decay", to an expressin of type "pointer to `T`" and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element in the array.  Hence why your `permutations` function has the signature

```
void permutations( char *str, int index, int n )
```

Since `str` has type `char *`, the *expressions* `str + index` and `str + i` *also* have type `char *`.  That’s why you got all the warnings when you changed `swap` to use `char` instead of `char *` arguments.  `str + index` is equivalent to the expression `&str[index]`, `str + i` is equivalent to `&str[i]`.

Remember that C passes all function arguments by value - the formal argument in the function definition is a distinct object in memory from the actual argument in the function call, so any change to the formal argument is not reflected in the actual argument.

If you define `swap` as

```
void swap(char p1, char p2) {
  char pmt;
  pmt = p1;
  p1 = p2;
  p2 = pmt;
}
```

and call it as

```
char a = 'a';
char b = 'b';

printf( "a = %c, b = %c\n", a, b );
swap( a, b );
printf( "a = %c, b = %c\n", a, b );
```

then you output would be

```
a = a, b = b
a = a, b = b
```

To swap the contents of `a` and `b`, you must use pointers:

```
void swap(char *p1, char *p2) {
  char pmt;
  pmt = *p1;
  *p1 = *p2;
  *p2 = pmt;
}
...
printf( "a = %c, b = %c\n", a, b );
swap( &a, &b );
printf( "a = %c, b = %c\n", a, b );
```

and now your output will be

```
a = a, b = b
a = b, b = a
```

---

1. Technically, we use it on an *lvalue*, which is an expression that designates an object such that the object may be read or modified.